# Can't fetch a WFS layer in EPSG:4326 with OpenLayers 6.3.5

Tags: postgis, openlayers, wfs

I am using `OpenLayers 6.3.5` and a WFS layer from `Mapserver` based on a view from `PostGIS` in `EPSG:4326`. I can load the WFS layer in **QGIS**.

I can't add the WFS in a map with `OSM`.

- **JS** :

```
const map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  view: new View({
    // zoom: 6.5,
    zoom: 15,
    center: fromLonLat([.7, 47.5])
  })
});

const osmSource = new OSM({})

const osm = new TileLayer({
  title: "OSM",
  source: osmSource,
  opacity: .7
})

map.addLayer(osm)
...
   const prescriptionSource = new VectorSource({
    format: new GeoJSON(),
    loader: function(extent, resolution, projection) {
      const url = 'http://.../mapserv.exe?MAP=c:/ms4w/.../ol_prescription.map&' +
              'service=WFS&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=prescription&outputFormat=geojson&SRSNAME=EPSG:4326&' + 
              'bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',' + 'EPSG:3857'
        fetch(url)
          .then(response => console.log(response.json()))
          .then(data => {
            const features = prescriptionSource.getFormat().readFeatures(data)
            features.forEach( feature => feature.setId(feature.get('pk')))
            features.forEach (feature => prescriptionArray.push(feature))
            prescriptionSource.addFeatures(features)
            //console.log(prescriptionArray)
          })
    },//fin loader
    strategy: bbox,  
  })

const prescription = new VectorLayer({
    declutter: true,
    source: prescriptionSource,    
    style: stylePrescription
    });

  map.addLayer(prescription)
```

- The error:
  In the console is :

[image]

Indeed, the `response` is empty (`array.length=0`) because the `fetch` is not working but I can't see the reason.

Comment: I think it should be `outputFormat=application/json`.

Comment: In `.then(response => console.log(response.json()))` `console.log` does not return the json, it returns undefined.  Use `.then(response => response.json())` and if you need to log the json use `console.log(data)` in the following `then` clause.  Also `readFeatures` can handle data as either json or text, if `response.json()` causes an error use `response.text()` so `console.log(data)` will report whatever is returned.

Comment: @TomazicM `syntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<?xml vers"... is not valid JSON` is returned.
@Mike `console.log(data)` returns an empty array as well. With `response.text()`, the feature property is empty.

Comment: What output formats are advertised in the WFS 1.1.0 GetCapabilities response, for a GetFeature request?

Comment: @nmtoken I get `<ows:Parameter name="outputFormat">
<ows:Value>text/xml; subtype=gml/3.1.1</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>geojson</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>application/json</ows:Value>
</ows:Parameter>`

Comment: first message updated with the second `EPSG` in the URL : it has to be `3857` (and not `4326`), same as the map.

Comment: What actual WFS GetFeature request is generated?  When you fire that off in a browser do you get some json, or an XML error message.

Comment: @nmtoken features are returned as expected with the updated `EPSG:3857` code (see above). But now I have duplicate features despite of `features.forEach( feature => feature.setId(feature.get('pk')))`

Comment: This is for separate question.